# Control a process using webforms

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, process, webforms

I am trying here to find a solution to control a process I launch via webforms.

I know it is quite easy to start-stop it using System.Diagnostics.Process class.

What I am trying to achieve is to send data to the process (a terraria server). Basically the server itself when it is launched correctly you can write inside it some commands like kick/ban/save/exit etc.

I'd like to write those commands but remote controlled via a webforms application.

The nearest solution I've thinked would have been to call the server via a daemon I would write that would work as gateway between the webforms commands and the server application. Is that the right way to do things ? Or is there any easier way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for the **BackgroundWorker class** that was introduced in .Net 3.5?
To execute a time-consuming operation in the background, you create a BackgroundWorker, and then listen for events that reportt the progress of your operation and signal when your operation is finished. It executes on a separate thread.

The [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) has some examples that might help you figure out if this is for you.

Or you could just use a **web service or WCF**, couldn't you? You can either host the web service on a web server or as a Windows service.

Comment: The idea is not bad, tho the problem with that is that it can't listen forever (since it's a web site after all)

Comment: If you don't need to listen for the process to end, then calling a web service will work. You just don't have a callback. You call the service to do its task, and you don't wait around for a response. You do need some way to ascertain when a process failed, such as logging. The service can be a WCF call to a Windows service that doesn't return anything. Check out WCF. I think it can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably start the process on application start and keep a reference to it in a static variable. You'll also need to attach to the `OutputDataReceived` event so you can record any data the process sends to its StandardOutput stream.

The idea is that the process will be running on the server and the web application will be silently recording any information it sends. When a request comes the buffer will be sent to the user and cleared.

The user can also send commands which the web application will forward to the process through its `StandardInput` stream.

I haven't tried it but it could possibly work. You will also need to consider what will happen if the application pool recycles. For best results I think you should disable autorecycling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the best way, make windows service that will control and monitor the process and into that windows service build API for a ASP.NET (webforms) application.

ASP.NET application can automatically refresh page (via javascript or meta refresh tag) and get new status from windows service that is controling your process, and event better you can build javascript application and get new status data and send commands with ajax, so there will be no need for whole page refresh.